# In Apex, what is the difference between the "execution context" and a transaction?

Tags: transaction, executioncontext

What are the boundaries of the execution context? What are the boundaries of a transaction?

Comment: Does this help? https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000187163&language=en_US

Comment: @Bachovski Honestly, it doesn't. It only serves to muddy the waters as far as I can tell.

Comment: can you please add more details & specifics to your question.. it will help the members to understand it from your point of view and answer better. single line questions are tough to understand and might not get answers exactly what you want.

Comment: That makes it a bit more confusing... so "per-transaction" limits are really "per-context"? That's what that article is saying to me. If so, what are the boundaries of the execution context?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've come at this from the perspective of when the logging records.

The first and last thing the Apex log records will be EXECUTION_STARTED and EXECUTION_FINISHED respectively.

From [Debug Log Details](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_debug_log_details.htm&language=en_US)

> **Execution Units**
>   An execution unit is equivalent to a transaction. It contains everything that occurred within the transaction. The execution is delimited by EXECUTION_STARTED and EXECUTION_FINISHED.

From [What's considered an "execution context"?](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000187163&language=en_US) ([via Bachovski's comment](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/81361/in-apex-what-is-the-difference-between-the-execution-context-and-a-transactio#comment107185_81361)):

> An execution context is the context information available during the lifetime of a transaction. Transactions are requests initiated by users when they update a record in the UI, use the API to upload records, etc.

From [Apex Transactions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_transaction.htm)

> An Apex transaction is sometimes referred to as an *execution context*. Both terms refer to the same thing. This guide uses the Apex transaction term.

So, each execution context has a corresponding transaction. For all intents and purposes they are one and the same thing.

Limits are applied per Apex Transaction. See [Per-Transaction Apex Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm#transaction_gov_limits_section)

There are some exceptions for certified managed packages (Aloha Apps?). See [Per-Transaction Certified Managed Package Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm#certified_pkg_limits_section)

If the overall execution terminates with an exception rather than completing successfully then the transaction will be rolled back. There are finer level DML transaction controls using database savepoints, but the overall execution transaction can still be rolled back for an unhandled exception. See [Transaction Control](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_transaction_control.htm).

Comment: I appreciate your answer, and I'm wondering this: I was told that an Apex static variable was scoped to the execution context. Is that true? It's value is only reset per context/transaction? Is is set in the transaction, what is its value outside the transaction?

Comment: The static variable will stay in scope for the execution context. This is commonly used for preventing trigger recursion. Different execution contexts will have their own state variables - i.e. you won't get cross talk between the execution contexts via static variables.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that the difference is that a transaction is the event that is happening, while an execution context is the system information associated with that event.